# Excecuting a Javascript once per browser session (window)

Tags: javascript, session

I have a simple Javascript code I want to run once per browser session, in a given website.

To clarify:

1. I open a browser session (window), say, Firefox.
2. I go to a certain webpage matched in Greasemonkey (say, google.com).
3. My script runs.
4. I fully refresh the wepbage (CTRL+F5), and the script no longer runs because it runs only once per session.

How can this be done? I mean, how can a simple script consisted only of one function, could be **limited to run only once in a browser session**, in a particular website matched in Greasemonkey?

Comment: Are the `DOMContentLoaded` event handlers currently dispatched more than once? What is purpose of calling `document.querySelector(".header-nav-item-sign-in").click()` and `document.querySelector("[type=submit]").click()` within `DOMContentLoaded` event handlers?

Comment: One takes you to the sign in page, one clicks submit for details already saved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LocalStorage` to do that. I have the whole logic explained in the comments.

```js
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  // First timer
  if (!localStorage.getItem("oldUser")) {
    localStorage.setItem("oldUser", true);
    executeYourCode();
  }
} else {
  // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
  // Use the above cookie method.
}
```

Comment: I've updated the question with a code dealing with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.localStorage` to set a parameter `isCalled = true`

Here docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Man, seriously? Not good. `:(`

Comment: Why not ? just because we wrote the answers at the same time or you give direct answer and I don"t ?